# Bi-directional one to one mapping only working one way

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jhipster

For some reason with this setup, when saving the transaction with a nested ticket. It will create both and then connect the two. However when I use the transaction repository to find the transaction it will have an attached ticket however when I use the ticket repository and find the ticket, it doesn't have the attached transaction. I generated this relationship with jhipster jdl, not sure what is going wrong here.

Transaction.java

```
...
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "person", "event", "transaction", "nameTags" }, allowSetters = true)
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(unique = true)
private Ticket tickets;

public Ticket getTickets() {
    return this.tickets;
}

public Transaction tickets(Ticket ticket) {
    this.setTickets(ticket);
    return this;
}

public void setTickets(Ticket ticket) {
    this.tickets = ticket;
}
...
```

Ticket.java

```
...
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "tickets", "membershipLevel", "person", "event" }, allowSetters = true)
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "tickets")
private Transaction transaction;

public Transaction getTransaction() {
    return this.transaction;
}

public Ticket transaction(Transaction transaction) {
    this.setTransaction(transaction);
    return this;
}

public void setTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
    if (this.transaction != null) {
        this.transaction.setTickets(null);
    }
    if (transaction != null) {
        transaction.setTickets(this);
    }
    this.transaction = transaction;
}
...
```

---

**Edit:**

Here is the generated SQL output, it is showing here just a normal select wihtout joins from both but transaction has the ticket_id in the transaction table while ticket is doing the same but has no reference and would need to do a join but is not.

```
Hibernate: insert into ticket (cost_per_ticket, count, event_id, person_id, picked_up, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into transaction (cost_sub_items_purchased, date, donation, event_id, event_donation, generic_sub_items_purchased, membership_level_id, notes, number_of_memberships, person_id, tickets_id, total_amount, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select transactio0_.id as id1_23_, transactio0_.cost_sub_items_purchased as cost_sub2_23_, transactio0_.date as date3_23_, transactio0_.donation as donation4_23_, transactio0_.event_id as event_i10_23_, transactio0_.event_donation as event_do5_23_, transactio0_.generic_sub_items_purchased as generic_6_23_, transactio0_.membership_level_id as members11_23_, transactio0_.notes as notes7_23_, transactio0_.number_of_memberships as number_o8_23_, transactio0_.person_id as person_12_23_, transactio0_.tickets_id as tickets13_23_, transactio0_.total_amount as total_am9_23_ from transaction transactio0_
Hibernate: select ticket0_.id as id1_22_, ticket0_.cost_per_ticket as cost_per2_22_, ticket0_.count as count3_22_, ticket0_.event_id as event_id5_22_, ticket0_.person_id as person_i6_22_, ticket0_.picked_up as picked_u4_22_ from ticket ticket0_
```

Comment: It's unfortunate that you named your entity as Transaction, it adds confusion. Have you checked that the JPA transaction has been committed? Have you enable debug log level on transactions and show_sql?

Comment: Added the sql generated above, and for this case Transaction only refers to the transaction entity class.

Comment: Yes but my question was about JPA transactions whether the select was executed in same transaction as the insert  or not. I'm surprised that the select does not include a join

Comment: Not seeing any transactions in the logs but might not have the correct log level settings for it. What's the best way to see the transactions?

Comment: Note: if after saving the ticket nested inside the transaction (and ticket is mapped to transaction) if I take the ticket and then resave it by nesting the transaction inside of it, it works correctly (ticket now has transactions list when pulling from DB). However the generated SQL list is exactly the same between the two whether I do the second step of saving ticket again with transaction inside it.